# Remove empathy from debian 6.0

Tags: debian, gnome, synaptic

I want to remove empathy from debian 6.0. But when I try to do it, Synaptic tells that it will remove gnome and gnome-dekstop env.

So how to remove empathy without removing gnome?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get remove empathy
aptitude keep-all
```

This is because you installed Gnome by metapackage, rather then selective packages.
More information about this problem is in this post:

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=39045#p229130

Comment: first command tells me that it will remove gnome and gnome-desktop-env and bunch for autoremove %)